# Shortest path between moving objects

Tags: python, path, minimum-spanning-tree

I've been searching around for an algorithm like this but I can't seem to find one. Is there a way to determine the shortest travel time from A to B considering that both A and B have different starting speeds and positions and that there are N other points around that have different starting speeds and positions as well. Suppose that you can only transfer to points that are on either your position or behind, how would you find the shortest time from A to B in Python?

Comment: Why Nodes have speeds?

Comment: Imagine the nodes as cars that are moving on a highway and you can only go to a car that's still behind you.